# How to hide all toolbars in Google Chrome without going full screen?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, fullscreen, toolbar

I would like to hide everything except the webpage content in Google Chrome. This means I want to hide tabs, omnibar, bookmarks bar and so on.

I've found out that the Presentation Mode is quite nice for this. You just hit <kbd>Shift⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and you can enjoy the clutter free web surfing. I can't figure out how to use the Presentation Mode without going fullscreen? Is it even possible?

My aim is to get rid of all the toolbars in Google Chrome. I would like to know if there is any other way to do it in case Presentation Mode doesn't work in windowed mode.

I use OS X. However I don't think my problem is platform specific.